# How does StackOverflow do its question revision history?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list, technology

I'm assuming each revision is stored in the database, but what tools/libraries/technologies do they use to show the graphical diff?

Comment: You should reword this so it's not a specific question about SO

Comment: Yeah but I'm more curious about finding out what SO used than a general question about diff tools.

Comment: This question has been re-asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66204/how-does-stackoverflow-implement-its-revision-history

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure about the GUI display but I am guessing it's custom and probably not that hard once you parse the diff output and apply styles to it.

The real work happens using a DIFFing engine which determines the difference between two blobs. There are quite a few .NET engines/library for determining the difference.

- [A Generic, Reusable Diff Algorithm](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx) on codeproject  (preferred)
- [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/)
- [Diff/Merge/Patch Library for C#/.NET](http://razor.occams.info/code/diff/) by Joshua Tauberer