# What is the Stack Overflow text comparison technology?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does StackOverflow do its question revision history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66202/how-does-stackoverflow-do-its-question-revision-history)

Someone corrected my post. I found [the representation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5326553/revisions) of both versions helpful.

What is the name of the concept? What does Stack Overflow use for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Jeff's 2009 blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/mixing-oil-and-water-authorship-in-a-wiki-world.html), he uses [this algorithm](http://xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf) and [this implementation](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/DiffDoku.aspx).